# Firebase Admin SDK on app engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

is it possible to use Firebase on app engine standard environment? I am aware that the standard environment threading capabilities are very limited and since the Firebase SDK runs a background synchronization thread it might not be compatible. I've gave it a try and I've encountered the following error, which I can't seem to overcome:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

Here is the servlet code:

```
public class GeneratorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    FirebaseDatabase database = null;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
//        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
//        InputStream serviceAccount = classloader.getResourceAsStream("serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.applicationDefault())
//                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://app-name.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp defaultApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        this.database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(defaultApp);

    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println(this.database);
        this.loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
//        The following line throws the error
        DatabaseReference ref = this.database.getReference("/publiclyReadable");
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong or is it caused by the limitations of the standard environment? I chose the standard environment over flexible because flexible version is not recommended for a production use yet.

Thanks, Jan

Edit:
appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>doctor-appointment-system</application>
    <version>0</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <instance-class>B1</instance-class>
    <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Edit:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>generator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.bookingtimes.GeneratorServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>generatorinfo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.bookingtimes.GeneratorInfoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>generator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/times/generate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>generatorinfo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/times/change</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.0'
}

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
        port = 8080                 // default
    }

    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
        promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }
}

group = 'com.example.appengine'
version = '0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I switched to App Engine Flexible (which was straightforward) and everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database client can be used on App Engine Standard Environment, as long as you put it in manual scaling mode. See the [documentation on cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio).

We recently fixed a problem when using the SDK on App Engine ([release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java#wzxhzdk6version_404_-_january_17_2017wzxhzdk7)), so be sure to use the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. However after all your advice (switched to manual scaling and updated the library from 4.1 to 4.1.1) I am still getting the error. The error occurs only in the local environment, but I guess that's because it gets suppressed on the server. Have a nice day

Comment: @JanBeneš: one our engineers has been trying to reproduce the problem, but unfortunately unsuccessfully so far. Can you also share your web.xml, so that we can see how your GAE handlers are configured there?

Comment: I've added file to to original post. Thanks

Comment: I can provide anything else if needed. I hope I am not wasting anyone's time here with some stupid mistake.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I get this error in the local appengine dev server. I am using `appengine-api-1.0-sdk 1.9.64` and `firebase-admin 6.3.0`. Any idea why?